# Can't access faraday params on views

Tags: faraday, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an API which has a database and another rails APP without active record, I'm also using ActiveResource to manage some db queries

My Front-end app controller is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  skip_before_action  :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

and i have an action to authenticate user from my front end to the API

from the front-end i have this method

```
def create_session
  conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://localhost:3001')
  conn.post '/auth_user', { :email => params[:email], :password => params[:password] }
end
```

and on API

```
def auth_user
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])

    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://localhost:3000') 
    conn.post '/add_session', { :status => "right", :user => user.id }
  else
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://localhost:3000') 
    conn.post '/add_session', { :status => "wrong" }
  end
```

end

Note that i have access to params[:email] and params[:password] and i get the right status to the front end

Then inside the front end i cannot access params[:status] or params[:user] excpet on byebug
i tried to do session[:user_id] = params[:user] and it's not working

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and playing around, I found out that i was doing it the wrong way.

Because the action has been executed and all it's variable has gone -As far as i could understand- so i managed to get this info by executing:

```
conn.get '/auth_user'
```

Then i could receive a response with json info which i need.